# What to I put for $base_dn if I need to search two subfolders in LDAP and PHP

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

I only have a very basic understanding of doing LDAP searches. I'm using PHP with Laravel.

I'm trying to do a search for all users within my my `OU=USERS` directory. I have two subfolders within that: `OU=STAFF` and `OU="STUDENTS`. I want to be able to search for a specific `DN` by username within both of those directories. The problem is that I can only make my search work if I specify either the `STAFF` or `STUDENTS` directories. I currently have:

```
...
$base_dn = 'OU=USERS,DC=mysite,DC=mydomain,DC=edu';
$filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=$username))";

$result = ldap_search($connection, $base_dn, $filter);
$entries = ldap_get_entries($connection, $result);


foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $ldapUsername = $entry["sAMAccountName"][0];
    echo $ldapUsername;
    return;
}
```

It will work if I specify either

```
$base_dn = 'OU=STAFF,OU=MMM_USERS,DC=mmc,DC=mmm,DC=edu';
```

or

```
$base_dn = 'OU=STUDENTS,OU=MMM_USERS,DC=mmc,DC=mmm,DC=edu';
```

but not without them.

Overall, I'm just trying to validate a user based off of their username, which is also their `cn`, and their LDAP password. As far as I've been able to tell, however, I need to first get their `DN`, to try to `bind` to the connection with the `DN` and password, taken from a PHP form input.

Any advice on the specifics or the overall method of going about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your LDAP Server Implementation you could use an [extensible matching filter](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch#section-ExtensibleMatch-SearchWithinTwoContainers).

However, I suspect you are using Microsoft Active Directory and it does NOT support extensible matching as you wish to perform.

-jim